# app-engine-rest-server to raise KeyError("name %s already used" % model_name)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest

I'm playing with the project ap[pengine-rest-server](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/) to create the REST webservices for all the existing models. I got a strange error, the first time I query the browser: http://localhost:8080/rest/metadata/user, it gives me the result:

```
      <xs:schema>
      −
      <xs:element name="user">
      −
      <xs:complexType>
      −
      <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="key" type="xs:normalizedString"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="surname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ages" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="sex" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="updatedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="createdDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
```

But refreshing the page, gives me this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3185, in _HandleRequest
      self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3128, in _Dispatch
      base_env_dict=env_dict)
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 515, in Dispatch
      base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2387, in Dispatch
      self._module_dict)
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2297, in ExecuteCGI
      reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2195, in ExecuteOrImportScript
      script_module.main()
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/helloworld/main.py", line 48, in main
      rest.Dispatcher.add_models({"user": UserModel})
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/helloworld/rest/__init__.py", line 845, in add_models
      cls.add_model(model_name, model_type)
    File "/Users/foo/Documents/AppEngine/helloworld/rest/__init__.py", line 863, in add_model
      raise KeyError("name %s already used" % model_name)
  KeyError: 'name user already used'
```

Can someone give me the explanation on why it happens? Restarting the server, run on the browser again I get the xml result, but refreshing causes the error. Is it a bug in the appengine-rest-server application or it is in my code? My helloworld application is available for download [here](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/217235/helloworld-zip.html).

Comment: I had to smile at `name="sex" type="xs:boolean"`

Comment: haha, :D it is right, I should change it a little bit to add one more value ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a `main()` function, the App Engine caches your module and imports. Hence within the same runtime, you may call `add_models()` more than once. If you move the `rest` initialization code to module level (or into a function that gets called once during module initialization, not during every call to `main()`) it should work.